# What does "public List<ABC> abc {get; set; } = new List<ABC>();" this mean?

Tags: c#

```
public List<ABC> abc {get; set; } = new List<ABC>();
```

I have seen this code in one of my code review, can someone help me understand why that developer might have written it like this.

Comment: Tongue in cheek: because they're foolish and didn't realize collection properties shouldn't be settable. (Or, at the very least, that the setter ought to check for attempts to set to `null`.)

Comment: It's an auto-property with the default set to an empty non-null list.

Comment: This is an example of auto-property initialiser available from C# 6.0 - http://geekswithblogs.net/WinAZ/archive/2015/06/30/whatrsquos-new-in-c-6.0-auto-property-initializers.aspx

Comment: Probably because there is code that adds to or reads from `abc` and they didn't want to do a null check everywhere so it is initialized from the start.

Comment: Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public List<ABC> abc {get; set; } = new List<ABC>();
```

This declares a property named `abc` of type `List<ABC>`.
The property has a getter and a setter (so no readonly or something).

The `= new List<ABC>();` part **initializes** the property when the class gets instantiated to a new list. This is only executed once when the instance is constructed.

This syntax was new in C# 6.

Before that you needed to initialize the property in the constructor or use an explicit backing field:

```
private List<ABC> _abc = new List<ABC>();
public List<ABC> abc {
  get {return _abc; }
  set { _abc = value; }
}
```

Note that it's normally a bad idea to have a public setter here. In most cases you only want the consumer of the class to manipulate the *content* of the list, but not to exchange the whole list (reference) from outside.